# Print serialized data from phpmyadmin saved using cf7db

Tags: wordpress, serialization, foreach, contact-form-7

I want to build a custom php page that shown registered user from wp,the data saved from wp is a serialized data and i got problem to display. btw i am using contact form 7 database plugin.

i keep getting explode() expect parameter to be string and getting error on line 10.

```
 <?php
    //connect database
    $conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","testsaja2");
    //call a field from table
    $sql= "select form_value from wp_db7_forms";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    while($string=mysqli_fetch_array($result));
    $explode = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);

    foreach ($explode as $line) {
         ?>

    <?php
        foreach (unserialize($line) as $item => $value){
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td><b><?php echo $item . ": ";?></b></td>
        <td><?php if ($value == 'email'){


            foreach ($value as $data) {
                echo $data ;

            }

                    }
                    else {
                echo $value;
            }
            ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <br>
     <?php } ?>
     </table>
     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: can you print the results of `$string`

Comment: Are you using `echo` or `print_r` to see results?

Comment: i can print $string i am using echo.. i got this result  
a:4:{s:12:"cfdb7_status";s:6:"unread";s:8:"yourName";s:9:"mustaqeem";s:5:"email";s:18:"mus_eleh@yahoo.com";s:3:"fon";s:9:"011789456";}
@SudharshanNair

Comment: why are you using explode there?

Comment: i want it to be shown row by row in a table, i try not to use before it gives me one straight line in a row instead of it goes into row by row in a table @SudharshanNair

Comment: Please mention what you want exactly

Comment: i want all my data saved in wp shown in a table in a custom php page like in customer service page as a registered user.  yet problem is the data displayed in one long row .@SudharshanNair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code to this.

```
    <?php
//connect database
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","","testsaja2");
//call a field from table
$sql= "select form_value from wp_db7_forms";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($string=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $unserialize = unserialize($string['form_value']);
    foreach ($unserialize as $item => $value){
?>
    <tr>
    <td><b><?php echo $item . ": ";?></b></td>
    <td><?php echo $value; ?> </td>
    </tr>

    <?php 
    } }?>
 </table>
```

Comment: invalid argument in line 10 sir in this line
    foreach (unserialize($string) as $item => $value){  @SudharshanNair

Comment: it gives error like before and also error unserialized() expect to be string @SudharshanNair

Comment: Modified my answer. Please check now